# C++/Lua: Implement Qt/QtLua with QWebView

Tags: c++, qt, lua, cross-platform, qwebview

I'm planning to write a cross-platform project in C++, which will run a Lua engine. I'd like to write the main program for that project including the GUI in Lua. And to make it even easier, I want to write the GUI in HTML and therefore I need an additional library, hopefully QtLua which is based on Qt.

From what I heard, implementing QtLua into the Lua engine shouldn't be too hard and Qt has a nice class called [QWebView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebview.html) that should allow me to write HTML GUIs. But I'm wondering about 2 things:

- Is it cross-platform capable?
- Is QWebView even part of QtLua?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answers to both questions i think you should find here http://www.nongnu.org/libqtlua/

There's this part that says

> QtLua is not designed to develop an application in pure Lua but rather to extend a Qt C++ application using Lua as scripting language.

Therefore, if your application is built/based on Qt and only extended using Lua, it should be cross-platform capable.

And for your second question; `QWebView` is used to view and edit web content, `QtLua` or `QtScript` is used to provide support for application scripting. `QWebView` is not part of `QtLua` plus i don't see any member of the `QWebView` class that has any connection with scripting